# intellisense for empty Win32 projects

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When I create a empty Win32 project. My intellisense stopped working. Is it possible to get it working for empty Win32 Projects with 1 source file ? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Usually you can fix intellisense by simply restarting Visual Studio or waiting some time.
If that still doesn't work you can delete the NCB file.

You can use `Ctrl+Space` to manually call up intellisense if it is available.

You can use `Ctrl+Shift+Space` to bring up a function parameter list.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, performing a build after adding a header file will update the program database with the header content.

Answer (score 0):

delete .ncb files in the solution folder and then open visual studio